# How does scoping affect defer execution in Swift?

Tags: swift

Consider the example code below:

```
enum Counter {

    case value(Int)

    mutating func add(value: Int) {

        // part A
        var orig = self
        defer { print("[part A] direct defer  : ", value, "+", orig, "=", self) }

        // part B
        do {
            var orig = self
            defer { print("[part B] do block defer: ", value, "+", orig, "=", self) }
        }

        if case let .value(prev) = self {
            self = .value(value + prev)
        }
    }
}

var c = Counter.value(0)
c.add(value: 10)
```

We have a simple counter enum that has one case which is used to store as Int counter. The function `add` adds a given `value` to the extracted counter value in `self` and then updating it.

There are two `print`s in defer statements, `part A` is scoped at the function level, and `part B` is scoped inside a local `do` block - otherwise, both prints a log of what value is getting added to what and what the final output will be.

Based on the code, the output should seem to be the same for both deferred `print`s; however, they are different:

```
[part B] do block defer:  10 + value(0) = value(0)
[part A] direct defer  :  10 + value(0) = value(10)
```

Why are they not the same?

Does the `do` block capture self and pass it to defer prematurely or is this intended design and a gotcha that one needs to be aware of?

Comment: `defer` blocks have C++ destructor semantics, they are executed immediately at the point execution leaves the block. The behavior you are seeing is by design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is as expected.

From [the Language Reference - Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/defer-statement) [emphasis mine]

> *Defer Statement*
>
> A defer statement is used for executing code just before transferring
>   program control **outside of the scope that the defer statement appears
>   in**.

So when the `A` `defer` in your example is executed, the mutating `add(value:)` function has finished its work, and hence increased `self` (to `10`). Whereas the `B` `defer` statement is placed within the `do` body, it is executed once that `do` transfer program control back to the immediate scope of `add(value:)`. Hence, when the `B` `defer` statement is executed, `self` is yet to be mutated.